value in __objc_selrefs segment appears not correct(too large) in IDA 7
I use IDA 7.0 to analyse a Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64, but value in __objc_selrefs seems wrong.I doubt something about little endian.
for example, address at 0x1004158B8 in IDA:

the value is 0x1000000033CCE8, but correct value should be 0x100033CCE8, because Hopper Disassembler analyses it correctly like this:

so I check out hex value:

Why Hopper Disassembler parses it correct but ida does't
as little endian rules, value in IDA should be right, when hex value is :
E8 CC 33 00 00 00 10 00
so value should be
10 00 00 00 33 CC E8
but this is too large, correct offset is 0x10033cce8
so I use big endian to analyse it with IDA again, still can't make it right, the value become to
E8 CC 33 00 00 00 10 00
How can I change settings in IDA to make it right like Hopper Disassembler do.
BTW, this is the binary:
sharingd

You are using a quite old version of IDA. IDA 7.0 has been released in 2017. Since that time a lot of changes to the Macho-O support had been implemented.
